# Videos tag are not working in firefox. React js

Tags: reactjs

So  I am coding a website using react js and I am having problems with video tag not working on Mozilla firefox. Its not showing the mask, as you can see in chrome.

The video format is mp4.

This is the website https://www.ai-medimaging.com/

This is my code :

```
                <video width="100%"
                    controls
                    playsInline
                >
                    <source src={vid} type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
```

Videos are working perfectly with chrome.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Almost certainly to do with the codec the video was encoded in. Support is not universal across browsers. Use an encoder to encode it to a common codec supported by both. "Mp4"'s have many different flavours and underlying structures.

Comment: @DaveNewton the video is not showing in the website. It shows in chromes but not in firefox

Comment: @adsy Thanks, going to  try some website to change the codec. Will give it a try, thanks again!

Comment: FWIT, video plays correctly on my FireFox 109.0, Ubuntu 22.04